# APC shared memory problems

Tags: php, freebsd, php-fpm

i have nginx+php-fpm and APC installed on a freebsd server, and i'm experiencing constant problems with php-fpm connected somehow with APC. php-fpm freezes in 'lockf' state (in `top`) and thus site is not working. 
i noticed that by lowering `apc.shm_size` to its default value 30 is helping php-fpm not to freeze, but 30Mb is not enough for me, because i store a lot of variables in APC. 
i noticed that raising `apc.shm_size` to higher values (as 60) makes php-fpm processes to use a lot more memory, practically all of the server physical memory, which is strange because as i understood those 60Mb are shared between all php-fpm processes and should not affect on memory usage of every php-fpm process.
i tried to change `apc.shm_segments` value to something more than 1 and got an error on restarting php-fpm:

```
PHP Startup: apc.shm_segments setting ignored in MMAP mode in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
Unknown(0) : Warning - PHP Startup: apc.shm_segments setting ignored in MMAP mode
```

so please tell me how do really those parameters affect on APC and why do php-fpm dies when using big amount of shared memory? what means `MMAP mode`?
i'm thinking of swithing to xcache, is it working with php-fpm and stable enough for production?

Answer (score 3):

About mmap:

Configure script of `apc` has directive:

```
  --disable-apc-mmap
                          Disable mmap support and use IPC shm instead
```

Also there is 3 types of locking:

```
  --enable-apc-sem
                          Enable semaphore locks instead of fcntl
  --enable-apc-spinlocks
                          Enable spin locks  EXPERIMENTAL
```

+Default `fcntl`. You can try `spinlocks` and see what happens

PS. This should be useful too: http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.setup.php

Answer (score 2):

If you have not increased the sysctl value **kern.ipc.shmmax** you need to do that. By default it is 32 MB, at least in my FreeBSD 8.0 and many Linux distributions as well.

Try `sysctl -w kern.ipc.shmmax=134217728` to increase to value to 128 megabytes. Then try to increase **apc.shm_size** again to be more than 30 MB.

If that helps, put your preferred kern.ipc.shmmax value to */etc/sysctl.conf* to make the change persist between reboots.

Comment: I get error: "kern.ipc.shmmax" is an unknown key
at ubuntu 11.10 oneiric

Comment: @john: you can find the known keys under `/proc/sys`. On my machine it was `kernel.shmmax`. (It did not make the error go away, though.)

Answer (score 0):

How did you set the memory?

`apc.shm_size=64` or `apc.shm_size=64M`, as it is in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php)?

The latter solved my similar problem.

Comment: M or not M, depends on apc/php version I think